# Configure Composer_providers to integrate AWS Cognito

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, amazon-cognito

Settings made on AWS Cognito:
[image: Settings made on AWS Cognito]

Hi, I am having a difficult time to configure COMPOSER_PROVIDER to use aws cognito services for authenticating hyperledger fabric REST server.

The following is the configuration, I tried, but failed.

```
COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
    "cognito": {
        "provider": "congito",
        "module": "passport-cognito",
        "userPoolID": "EXAMPLE ID",
        "clientID": "SAMPLE ID",
        "clientSecret": "Q4i_CqpqChCzbE-u3Wsd_tF0",
        "region::'ap-northeast-1',
        "authPath": "/auth/cognito",
        "callbackURL": "http://localhost:3000/auth/cognito/callback",
        "successRedirect": "/",
        "failureRedirect": "/"
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Hyperledger Composer supports the passport strategies here -> http://www.passportjs.org/packages/ and this isn't listed ?